# Writes to child subprocess.Popen.stdin don't work from within process group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, stdin

From within a Python script, I'm launching an executable in a subprocess (for anyone interested: it's the terraria server).

```
# script.py
server_process = subprocess.Popen("my_executable arg1 arg2", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

# My Bash shell
$ ps aux | grep my_executable
# I've removed everything but the PIDs and CLIs below
14701  my_executable arg1 arg2
```

`my_executable` starts writing to `stdout` as expected. However I can't seem to *write* to `stdin` from that same Python script

```
# script.py
server_process.stdin.write('exit\n')
server_process.stdin.flush()
```

`my_executable` terminates itself upon reading `exit`, so that should kill it: but nothing happens

Here's the wrinkle: I can write to `my_executable`'s `stdin` via `/proc` from a *separate* process (like my bash shell) just fine!

```
# Bash shell
$ sudo echo exit > /proc/14701/fd/0 # Works
$ python3 -c 'import os; os.system("sudo echo exit > /proc/14701/fd/0")' # Also works!
```

Putting that `os.system` call in the original script with `server_process.pid` doesn't work though

```
# script.py
os.system(f"sudo echo exit > /proc/{server_process.pid}/fd/0")
# sh: 1: cannot create /proc/14701/fd/0: Directory nonexistent
```

It seems like writes to `stdin` from a separate process (like my bash shell) work, whereas writes from within the process (group?) don't. What's going on here?

Comment: `<&0` does nothing at all. stdin is _already_ FD 0, so using `fdup2()` to copy 0 to 0 has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Anyhow, I don't know why you'd expect content written to FD 0 to "loop back" to the same process doing the writing. Let's say FD 0 is connected to `/dev/null` -- then writing to it goes nowhere at all. On the other hand, let's say it's a FIFO -- then it has separate read and write sides, and you can only read to the read side and only write to the write side, and using the wrong side the incorrect way will cause the operation reading from or writing to the wrong side to fail.

Comment: When you're interacting with an interactive shell _all three_ of `/dev/fd/0`, `/dev/fd/1` and `/dev/fd/2` will be handles on `/dev/tty` -- that's why interactive shells are different from things you run as a subprocess.

Comment: Anyhow, you can probably gather enough information to resolve the rest of your questions by running `ls -l /proc/self/fd` in all the various permutations of ways you might want to start a process, and comparing the results.

Comment: As for the problem that inspired the question -- of why the write from Python doesn't work -- that's a question I'd use `strace -f` (or, much more efficiently but with more work needed if you haven't set them up, ebpftrace or sysdig) to answer.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that when spawning a child process, it would share `stdout` and `err` but not `in`. I think that holds true for when you spawn a child process in bash via `my_command &`, and I erroneously generalized that in my head.

Ok, so agreed: the `<&0` does nothing, and I'll see what happens when I remove it. But I disagree about me "expect[ing] content written to FD 0 to "loop back" to the same process doing the writing." I'm trying to write to `my_executable`'s stdin from a python script. Both are in a single process *group* ofc, but they're different processes

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean about running that `ls -l` command in "all the various permutations of ways you might want to start a process." I'm only launching the process one way, and interacting with its `stdin` via `/proc` works: I'm wondering why I can't interact with it from Python. Although maybe `strace` will prove fruitful